# Does the “in” operator have side effects?

Tags: python

I have code which writes bytes to a serial port (pySerial 3.5) and then receives bytes.

The code should work for micropython too, which uses UART instead of pySerial. With UART, I have to add a small delay before reading.

The user should not have to pass an additional flag whether to add that delay, because the `serial_port` object is already platform specific, for example the UART implementation provides a `.any()` method which the pySerial implementation does not have.

So my first attempt is to check for this method, and only delay when it exists.

```py
def __init__(self, serial_port):
    self.serial_port.write(my_bytes)

    # When checking for any on serial_port, I receive no bytes.
    if "any" in self.serial_port:
        print("UART specific delay will happen here")
    # When instead checking with getattr(self.serial_port, "any", None), bytes come in

    raw_config = self.serial_port.read(128)
```

As soon as I add this `"any" in self.serial_port` check, the `read()` method **returns an empty byte array.**

When I remove the check, I get bytes again. When I replace the check by `getattr(self.serial_port, "any", None)`, I get bytes too. When I just run `time.sleep()` or anything else, I get bytes. When I add the `in` check, bytes are gone.

Why on earth? Isn't an `in` check supposed to be side effect free?

*(All runs were executed with pySerial ports only.)*

Comment: Think about it logically -- how could `in` work without reading from the serial port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by deceze, `in` just calls the `__contains__()` method. Depending on how this is implemented, it *can* have side effects.

A simple example to demonstrate this:

```py
class Example:

    def __contains__(self, x):
        print('Side effect!')


x = Example()
if 'something' in x:
    print('Found')
else:
    print('Not found')
```

Output:

```
Side effect!
Not found
```

In the case of your `serial_port` example, I guess the `__contains__()` method is implemented in such a way that it reads bytes until "any" is found, or until there are no more bytes. Consequently, all bytes are already consumed and your function returns an empty array.

NB: According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__):

> For objects that don’t define `__contains__()`, the membership test first tries iteration via `__iter__()`, then the old sequence iteration protocol via `__getitem__()`.

Answer (score 6):

This is not mentioned in the [PySerial documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/), but it is a consequence of the fact that the class inherits from [`io.IOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase) in the standard library. The documentation for `IOBase` states:

> `IOBase` (and its subclasses) supports the iterator protocol, meaning that an `IOBase` object can be iterated over yielding the lines in a stream.

So although the PySerial class does not actually implement the `__contains__` method, and in fact neither do any of the other classes in its hierarchy *including* `IOBase`, the iterator protocol [provides a different mechanism](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) for the `in` operator to work:

> For user-defined classes which do not define `__contains__()` but do define `__iter__()`, `x in y` is `True` if some value `z`, for which the expression `x is z or x == z` is true, is produced while iterating over `y`.

So, the `in` operator iterates over the stream in order to test membership, and that operation has the side-effect of consuming from the stream (because that's how iterating over an IO socket works in Python).

Answer (score 2):

As people in the comments said, `__contains__` is *often* called. In this particular case, it's probably consuming some sort of iterator/generator. Here's a simple example with a file handle:

`file.txt`:

```
hello
hello
```

```
>>> f = open("file.txt")
>>> f.read()
'hello\nhello\n'

>>> f = open("file.txt")
>>> "hello\n" in f  # iterates over all lines
True
>>> f.read()
''
>>> f.seek(0)
0
>>> f.read()
'hello\nhello\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

If `self.serial_port` is lazily evaluated/can only be iterated once this makes total sense.. Check this out and you'll see:

```
a = (x for x in (1,2,3,4,5)) # generator comprehension - will be evaluated lazily
print(list(a)) # [1,2,3,4,5]
a = (x for x in (1,2,3,4,5))
5 in a
print(list(a)) # []
a = (x for x in (1,2,3,4,5))
2 in a
print(list(a)) # [3,4,5]
```

hope you see how `in` can mess up your evaluation here :)

Note if you'd replace the generator comprehensions `(x for x in ...)` by list comprehensions `[x for x in ...]` then `in` wouldn't have any side effects like that because a list can be iterated multiple times and a list isn't created lazily.